# How to place "ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l" correctly into if statement

Tags: bash, sorting, if-statement, cut, tail

The output of "ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l" is 1
when the last 6 files has an equal value on a specific position in the filename, but how can i put this into a if / else statement for further checking?

I've tried this

```
if [ $(ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l) ==1 ]
then 
zabbix_sender -z zabcol-pp.domain.com -s dvs.backup -k frameoffset -o "OK"
else 
zabbix_sender -z zabcol-pp.domain.com -s dvs.backup -k frameoffset -o "Failed"
fi
```

But that does not work, so then tried so simplify the process by parsing the values into a offset.txt file and then checking if values are equal which works but not flawless, every once in a while not 6 but the last 5 files are parsed and the sixth is an empty line which is not equal so i get a 'failed' state while it is actually not....

```
ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 > ../offset.txt
if [ $(sort -u ../offset.txt | wc -l) == 1 ] 
then 
zabbix_sender -z zabcol-pp.domain.com -s dvs.backup -k frameoffset -o "OK"
else 
zabbix_sender -z zabcol-pp.domain.com -s dvs.backup -k frameoffset -o "Failed"
fi
```

Besides i think it is a not so elegant approach, so i want to get the piped version without placing it into a temp to work, but can't figure out on how to accomplish this...

Thank you very much in advance...

Comment: I'd perhaps investigate awk/Perl etc. for the above in the longer term, since the approach above spawns *5* separate processes!

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the equality `-eq`:

```
if [ $(ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
```

Comment: You're indeed super fast... :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hehe it was a small thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Brian Agnew's comments, provide additional help to reduce the pipes.

```
if [ $(ls -t |awk 'NR<=6{a[substr($0,16,2)]}END{print length(a)}') -eq 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have an answer that says to use `-eq`, it doesn't explain *why* you would need to, and even though you *should* use `-eq`, you don't necessarily *need* to.

Starting with your first attempt:

> ```
> if [ $(ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l) ==1 ]
> ```

The main thing that's wrong is `==1`. The `=` characters in this position have no special significance to the shell, it will treat `==1` as a single word. You need to ensure that there is a space, like so:

```
if [ $(ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l) == 1 ]
```

The second thing that could be wrong, but isn't necessarily wrong, is that `==` is specific to a few shells. In those shells, it is equivalent to the 100% standard and portable `=` test.

```
if [ $(ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l) = 1 ]
```

The third thing that could be wrong, but isn't necessarily wrong, is that `=` is a string comparison, whereas `-eq` is a numeric comparison. You can treat `wc`'s output as a string, and compare it to the string "1", and you would still get a match if and only if `wc` sees a single line. However, if there is any possibility that two strings will be different, but represent the same numeric value, for example `1`/`01`/ `1`, then you really do need the numeric comparison `-eq`:

```
if [ $(ls -tr | tail -n -6 | cut -c16-17 | sort -u | wc -l) -eq 1 ]
```